# How can I hold value in input without cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I append a text value with jquery. But when I was refresh the page, input value disappear. I can use jquery cookie but I don't want to use this method. How can I hold value in input without cookie. There is an example and jsfiddle demo below.

```
  <input type="text" id="couponInput" class="couponInput" placeholder="Coupon code" />                                                 
  <button type="button" id="couponApply" class="couponApply">APPLY   COUPON</button>                           
  <span class="removeCoupon"></span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.couponApply').click(function(event){

    var couponInputval = $(".couponInput").val();

    if(couponInputval == "x1"){

        alert('Coupon Applied!');
        $( ".removeCoupon" ).append( "Remove Coupon" );
        $(".couponInput, .couponApply").attr('disabled','disabled');          

         $('.removeCoupon').click(function(){
            $(".couponInput, .couponApply").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
           $(".removeCoupon").empty();
         });
    }

    else{
        alert('Error');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vsgfj05h/

Comment: You can use html5 `localStorage`, although that's not quite cross-browser yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the local storage instead of cookie.

It not working inside the jsfiddle. I think it's because jsfiddle uses iframe to display the results.

Simple usage:

```
if (localStorage.couponInputval) {
  $(".couponInput").val(localStorage.couponInputval)
}
localStorage.couponInputval = $(".couponInput").val();
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) Documentation

Comment: Thank you, I added code but it didn't work. I added the code after this block var couponInputval = $(".couponInput").val(); 
Is it wrong?

Comment: If you adding the `if` statement from my example above inside the `click` event listener. It's will working only when the button is clicked. So you will replace the localStorage and then trying to take the value back again. It's no sence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionStorage or localStorage - it's the best way to do it